# SQLCMD query - Adding in a products next due date (based on purchase order)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, sapb1

I am using a .bat and SQLCMD to get an export of data from my SQL Server.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
SQLCMD -S <server name> -d <database name> -U <username> -P <password> -Q
"set nocount on;
SELECT T0.ItemCode,
       T0.FrgnName,
       (SELECT cast(round(T3.Price,2,1) as decimal(18,2)) 
        FROM ITM1 T3 
        WHERE T3.ItemCode = T0.Itemcode AND T3.[PriceList] = '1'),
       cast(round(T1.Price,2,1) as decimal(18,2)), 
       CASE WHEN T2.OnHand - T2.IsCommited > 10 THEN '10' ELSE '0' END,
       T0.CodeBars 
FROM OITM T0 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode AND T1.[PriceList] = '2' 
INNER JOIN OITW T2 ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode AND T2.WhsCode = '01. Main' 
WHERE T0.ItemName NOT LIKE '%%DNU%%' 
  AND T0.PrchseItem = 'y' AND T0.FrozenFor = 'n' 
  AND T0.QryGroup2 = 'y' AND T0.QryGroup10 = 'n'"
 -s "," -o "\\serveraddress\stockfile.csv" -h-1 -s"~" -W -w 999
```

Essentially, I need to add in one final piece to the stock file - and that is the earliest *DocDueDate* from the *OPOR* table. There may be multiple purchase orders with the same product - so I definitely need to be able to get the data for the earliest date.

Within SAP and queries that I have been using, there is this which I can't seem to make work within the SQLCMD script:

```
ISNULL((SELECT top 1 r1.[DocDueDate] 
        FROM POR1 r 
        INNER JOIN OPOR r1 ON r.DocEntry = r1.DocEntry  
        WHERE r.[LineStatus] = 'O' 
          AND r.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode] 
        ORDER BY r1.[DocDueDate]), 0) AS 'PO Date'
```

I have attempted to simply plug this into the SQLCMD script, no joy. I then attempted to cull the `AS 'PO DATE'` but this didn't help.

I'm hoping that someone can please explain to why this isn't working for me.

Regards
Rick

Comment: What error do you receive in attempting the smaller SAP snippet?

Comment: It doesn't display an error message when I run the .bat - it simply just flashes up and disappears far too quickly.

Comment: At the end of your .bat add `start "" cmd /c "echo QUERY RESULTS!&echo(&pause"` to keep cmd window screen up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating your inline subquery to a derived table using an aggregate query to find max date. This avoids running query row by row but executed in just one call:

```sql
SELECT T0.ItemCode,
       T0.FrgnName,
       (SELECT CAST(ROUND(T3.Price,2,1) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
        FROM ITM1 T3 
        WHERE T3.ItemCode = T0.Itemcode AND T3.[PriceList] = '1'),
       CAST(ROUND(T1.Price,2,1) AS DECIMAL(18,2)), 
       CASE WHEN T2.OnHand - T2.IsCommited > 10 THEN '10' ELSE '0' END,
       T0.CodeBars,
       ISNULL(D.MaxDocDueDate, 0) AS [PO Date]
FROM OITM T0 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode AND T1.[PriceList] = '2' 
INNER JOIN OITW T2 ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode AND T2.WhsCode = '01. Main' 
INNER JOIN
   ( SELECT r.[ItemCode], MAX(r1.[DocDueDate]) As MaxDocDueDate
     FROM POR1 r 
     INNER JOIN OPOR r1 ON r.DocEntry = r1.DocEntry  
     WHERE r.[LineStatus] = 'O' 
     GROUP BY r.[ItemCode]
   ) D ON T0.[ItemCode] = D.[ItemCode]
WHERE T0.ItemName NOT LIKE '%%DNU%%' 
  AND T0.PrchseItem = 'y' AND T0.FrozenFor = 'n' 
  AND T0.QryGroup2 = 'y' AND T0.QryGroup10 = 'n'"
```

Comment: Your script works well within SQL Server Management Studio - but I am purposively using SQLCMD such that I can run it as a scheduled task to export out a CSV. Unless you can describe to me how I can do this with Studio - then I think I'll need to stick with SQLCMD.

Comment: Did you try running this query in your SQLCMD script? This was intended to replace the `SELECT` statement.